# Pourquoi "précédent" n'a-t-il pas la forme d'un adjectif verbal?

Tags: grammaire, étymologie, orthographe

Bonjour,

je faisais autrefois la faute d'orthographier "précédant" l'adjectif "précédent". Je trouve la forme néanmoins toujours convaincante (!): j'écrirais volontiers "la page suivante" après "la page précédante". Quelle est la raison sémantique ou étymologique de cette terminaison en -ent?

Merci

Comment: Bonne idée, tout a !

Comment: Je la trouve moins convainquente...

Comment: @ jlliagre haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Précédent » provient du latin « praecedens », d'où le e dans la terminaison.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent))  Empr. au lat. praecedens, -tis, part. prés. adj. de praecedere (v. précéder).

« Suivant », cependant remonte au participe présent de suivre, et comme toutes les terminaisons des participes présent sont écrites avec a, l'adjectif a aussi un a.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suivant)) II. Adj. 1. 1remoit. xiiies. suiant « qui vient après quelqu'un » (Jean Renart, Galeran de Bretagne, éd. L. Foulet, 5573); 1276 sywant (13 mai, Let. du cte de Gloc., Cart. N, fo57b), A. Douai ds Gdf. Compl.); 2. 1666 « qui suit quelqu'un, l'escorte, lui sert de domestique » demoiselle suivante (Furetière, Rom. bourg., édit. de la bibl. elzév., p. 233 ds Livet Molière t. 3, p. 652); 3. 1694 « qui va suivre (dans un énoncé, une énumération...) » pour les raisons suivantes (Ac.). Part. prés. adj. et subst. de suivre*. Bbg. Kesik (M.). Exophore/endophore: le fonctionnement de suivant. L'Inform. gramm. 1987, no35, pp. 3-9. − Lebègue (R.). Notes sur le personnage de la servante. R. Hist. litt. Fr. 1983, t. 83, p. 10. − Quem. DDL t. 9.

Comment: C'est clair, merci!